# cronometro que inicia no button fica um em cima do outro

Tags: javascript, button

Entao sou iniciante e queria uma dica como fazer para quando clicar no botao nao ficar 2 cronometro ao mesmo tempo um em cima do outro acredito que com clearInterval resolva mais  fiquei sem ideia de onde coloca-lo

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer= duration, min, sec

  setInterval(function () {
    min = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    sec = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    min= min<10 ? '0' + min :min;
    sec= sec<10 ? '0' + sec :sec;
    display.textContent = min + ':' + sec;

    if (--timer<0) {
        timer = duration;
    }  
  }, 1000);
}

function iniciarContagem() { 
    var fourmin = 60* 4; //conversão para segundos
    display = document.querySelector('#timer'); //elemento para exibir o timer no document html

    startTimer(fourmin, display); //inicia as functions ou chama as functions
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = iniciarContagem;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
<input id="btn" type="button" 
       value="Iniciar Contagem" 
       onclick="iniciarContagem()">
```

Answer (score 0):

É preciso "finalizar" o timer anterior antes de iniciar um novo usando o `clearInterval` como já mencionou na pergunta.

Pode associar o timer a uma variável para facilitar isso, e limpar o anterior antes de iniciar um novo. Veja o exemplo abaixo, adicionei comentários nos pontos alterados do seu código:

```js
// para melhorar a leitura, coloquei todas as variáveis aqui
let timerAtual, timer, min, sec;

function funcaoTimer() {
    min = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    sec = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    min= min<10 ? '0' + min :min;
    sec= sec<10 ? '0' + sec :sec;
    display.textContent = min + ':' + sec;

    if (--timer<0) {
        timer = duration;
    } 
}

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  timer= duration
  // atribui o timer a variavel "timerAtual" para fazer o clear depois
  timerAtual = setInterval(funcaoTimer, 1000);
}


function pararContagem() {
 if (timerAtual != undefined) {
       console.log("parando contagem");
       clearInterval(timerAtual);
 }
}

function iniciarContagem() { 
    var fourmin = 60* 4; //conversão para segundos
    display = document.querySelector('#timer'); //elemento para exibir o timer no document html
    
    // aqui verifica se já existe o timer e faz o clear ////////
    pararContagem();
    
    startTimer(fourmin, display); //inicia as functions ou chama as functions
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = iniciarContagem;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
<input id="btn" type="button" 
       value="Iniciar Contagem" 
       onclick="iniciarContagem()">
       
<input id="btn" type="button" 
       value="Parar Contagem" 
       onclick="pararContagem()">
```

Coloquei a parte do código que para o contador numa função separada e coloquei um botão para executar só essa parte, assim pode além de reiniciar o contador, apenas parar.

Comment: so ficou um problema que quando chega a zero o cronometro continua  com numeros negativos

Comment: coloquei uma condiçao na funcaoTimer depois de dizer o conteudo do display display.textContent = min + ':' + sec;     if (min <= 00 && sec<=00) {//condiçao para parar o display
        clearInterval(timerAtual);
    } pronto ficou otimo valeu a força

Comment: *"so ficou um problema que quando chega a zero...."* mas isso já é outra dúvida :)  o problema de não reiniciar o cronometro está resolvido na resposta, se ela foi útil não esqueça de votar